# Django filter many to many

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

If I have products that only can be sold is some regions. Also a customer can belong to several regions.
Example:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

class Product(models.Model):
    productname = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

class Region(models.Model):
    regionname = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")


class CustomerRegionLink(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)

class ProductRegionLink(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
```

If I now have a Customer object. How can I filter out which products can be ordered?

I have tried versions of:

```
thecustomer = Customer.objects.get(id=1)
prods = ProductRegionLink.object.filter(region__in=thecustomer.customerregionlink.all())
```

This errors like: 
ValueError: Cannot use QuerySet for "CustomerRegionLink": Use a QuerySet for "Region".

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
thecustomer = Customer.objects.get(id=1)
prods = ProductRegionLink.object.filter(region__in=[cr_link.region for cr_link in thecustomer.customerregionlink.all()])
```

As in your current query you are trying to find region in customerregionlink queryset not in region queryset or list.

Comment: I'd use `.values_list('region', flat=True)` instead of list comprehension - better SQL query behind the scenes